# How to show Notifications after every 4 hours?

Tags: android, service, notifications

*I want the notification to be shown after every 4 hours after the Activity is Destroyed.*

**Here's my code snippet of main activity's onDestroy().**

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                                                                       PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(contentIntent);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*00*00*04, contentIntent);
}
```

**and here is my Notification.class code snippet:**

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class Notification extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);

        NotificationManager notificationManager
            = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        android.app.Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent,
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("It's been so Long!!!")
            .setSubText("Please return back to App")
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setVibrate(new long[] {1000,1000,1000,1000})
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Important Notification")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am working on this since so many days but I am unable to complete the task.

Any Help would be highly Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

***HELP please!!!***

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying by 0 here:

```
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
           System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000*00*00*04, contentIntent);
```

The third parameters is the "interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of the alarm", so your alarm will be only be fired once because the interval is, well, zero. You need to change the third parameter to four hours, which in milliseconds translates to 3600 * 1000 * 4.

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
           System.currentTimeMillis(), 3600 * 1000 * 4, contentIntent);
```

Comment: thanks, and if i want notification to be shown after every 10 seconds?

Comment: Then change 3600 * 1000 * 4 to 10 * 1000, which is 10,000 milliseconds

Comment: No bro it;s not happening!! i destroyed the App and then waited for 10 seconds but i got no notification!!! What to do now???

Comment: Follow this tutorial step by step and see if you can get their code to work: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Sorry to say bro but it's still not WORKING! I am unable to understand the Problem here!

Comment: What to do now Bro? Can you help anymore regarding this?